# Need help in doing math calculation for natural logarithm (ln)

Tags: c, math

How do I write a function for this in C language?

y = 20 ln (x + 3) ?

How do I write the ln function?

Comment: By any chance, do you intend to use the polynomial expression for logarithm i.e. ln(x) = (x - 1) - ((x-1)^2)/2 + ((x-1)^3)/3 - ((x-1)^4)/4 ... If not then i believe you already got many answers

Comment: did you ever try googling for "C natural logarithm"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <math.h> 

double fun(double x)
{
    return 20 * log( x + 3 );  //base-e logarithm!
}

//usage
double y = fun(30);
```

For base-10 logarithm, use `log10()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
double myfunction(int x){
    return  (20* log(x+3) );
}
```

?

And you call it :

```
double y = myfunction(yourX);
```

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <math.h>` and to link against the math library if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>
double function(double x)
{
     double y = 20 * log(x + 3.0);
     return y;
}
```

Comment: This is C++; the question asks for C.

Comment: Remove the `std::` and the useless temp variable.

Comment: Changed it to C. I kept the variable to keep it concrete in relation to the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

The log function in the c library is performs a natural logarithm ('ln'). See this for more details: [CPlusPlus - log](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log/)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is tagged C++, questioner is asking for a C implementation:

```
#include <math.h>

double myFunction(double x) {
    return 20.0 * log(x + 3.0);
}
```